# Неопределенное количество аргументов функции

Tags: функции, c++

Возможно ли декларировать функцию именно в C++, так, чтобы кол.-во аргументов было динамичным. К примеру в `JavaScript` допускается такой синтакс.

```
function func()
{
    i=16; // номер аргумента 
    return arguments[i]; // возвращает 17-ый аргумент
}
```

Нужен аналог для C++. Если можно, немного кода ))

Comment: @Даффф, а вообще ответ на такой вопрос (и многие другие) легко читается в файле `/usr/include/stdio.h` (и других системных инклюдниках).

Это просто совет, а ни в коем случае, не порицание Вашего вопроса.

Comment: А как вы узнаете тип аргумента? Вы уверены, что не хотите передать просто `std::vector`?

Answer (score 7):

[[@Даффф](/users/2168/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D1%84)](/users/2168/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D1%84), только **никогда** (в серьезных программах) не используйте просто указатели для доступа к аргументам из списка с переменным их количеством.

Это абсолютно не переносимо. Например, в x86-64 первые 6 аргументов передаются в регистрах.

Надо пользоваться функциями

```
   #include <stdarg.h>

   void va_start(va_list ap, last);
   type va_arg(va_list ap, type);
   void va_end(va_list ap);
   void va_copy(va_list dest, va_list src);
```

(см. `man 3 stdarg`)

Comment: Offtop: странно, когда рейтинг непосредственных ответов на вопрос ниже остальных. Такое ощущение, что оценки ставят не по критерию: `верно/неверно`, а по критерию `нравится/не нравится`. ["Хочу голосовать за теги!"](http://forum.vingrad.ru/index.php?showtopic=362967&view=findpost&p=2551214)

Comment: @mega, если бы оба *непосредственных* ответа не содержали вредной рекомендации обращаться к элементам списка, отталкиваясь от адреса первого параметра, то я бы и не подумал что-то писать.

Comment: @avp, а у меня к Вам претензий нет. Вы совершенно верно дополнили ответ, но именно дополнили, а не ответили.

Comment: Действительно, про точки в прототипе повторяться не стал, правда в комментарии непосредственно под вопросом посоветовал почитать `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 4):

Придумал решение с использованием variadic templates. Немножко не по теме правда, т.к. номера используемых аргументов нужно знать во время компиляции, но может понадобится кому-нибудь:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <int N, typename FirstArg, typename... Args>
struct NthArgHelper {
    static_assert(N > 0, "N should be positive");
    static_assert(N < sizeof...(Args) + 1, "N is too large");

    typedef typename NthArgHelper<N - 1, Args...>::Type Type;

    static Type&& get(FirstArg&&, Args&&... args) {
        return NthArgHelper<N - 1, Args...>::get(args...);
    }
};

template <typename FirstArg, typename... Args>
struct NthArgHelper<0, FirstArg, Args...> {
    typedef FirstArg Type;

    static Type&& get(FirstArg&& arg, Args&&...) {
        return std::forward<FirstArg>(arg);
    }
};

template <int N, typename... Args>
typename NthArgHelper<N, Args...>::Type&& NthArg(Args&&... args)
{
    return NthArgHelper<N, Args...>::get(args...);
}

template <typename... Args>
void test(Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "Argument 2: " << NthArg<2>(args...) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Argument 0: " << NthArg<0>(args...) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   test(10, 3.1415, "Hello!");
   std::cout << "=======================\n";
   test(1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 5, 6, 6);
   return 0;
}
```

Результат [по ссылке](http://ideone.com/b391gs).

Comment: В исследованиях, думаю, будет интересно, если, конечно, нам когда-нибудь дадут наконец эту возможность, конвертирования вопросов в исследование (`TODO: сделать вопросом, сделать исследованием`).

Answer (score 3):

Про `stdarg` уже сказали. Чудненько.

Но в С++11 появился новый мощный инструмент - шаблоны с переменным числом аргументов (variadic templates). Подробно описывать не буду, можете почитать [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template), а потом погуглить. Также неплохое описание имеется в новом издании Джосаттиса The CPP Standard Library (вроде бы должны скоро по-русски издать).

Answer (score 2):

Да, в C++ возможна функция с переменным количеством аргументов. Для этого в список формальных параметров надо поставить многоточие ...

```
void someFunction(int n, ...);
```

Для доступа надо использовать указатель, каждый следующий аргумент "отстоит" от другого на sizeof указанного типа, поэтому надо приращивать указатель на эту величину с помощью += например. Чтобы узнать конец списка аргументов используют такие приемы - либо один из явных аргументов означает количество фактических "неопределенных" аргументов, либо используют значение-маркер для последнего аргумента (например 0, NULL, -1 - главное чтобы такое значение не было "легальным" по логике самой функции
Подробнее [тут](http://coderlife.ru/progr/peremennoe-chislo-parametrov-v-cc-funkciyax.html) или [тут](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/418970.1). Вообще эта тема легко гуглится, поэтому тут не особо стараюсь дать полную инфу по теме, но если что будет непонятно - спрашивайте, помогу

Comment: Да, именно то что искал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, да, в C++ есть возможность создания функций с неизвестным заранее числом параметров. Для этого используется вот такой синтаксис:

```
void VariableArgs(int first,...) // запятая, кстати, необязательна
{
   int* pFirst = &first;

   // что-то там    
}
```

Как видите, для указания того, что число параметров неизвестно, ставится многоточие. При этом следует помнить, что у такой функции должен быть определен первый параметр (его тип и имя), так как взаимодействие со всеми остальными аргументами основывается на действиях с указателями - доступ к последующим аргументам осуществляется косвенно - через указатель на первый. Добавляя смещение к pFirst вы сможете обращаться к следующим аргументам функции. Для вашего примера это будет выглядеть так: pFirst[16].

Нужно сказать, что данный способ - не слишком удачное решение, так как в этом случае могут возникнуть проблемы с  типобезопасностью - в принципе, вы можете передавать аргументы любых типов, и компилятор ничего не скажет, но в рантайме это чревато ошибками.   Сответсвенно, данны способ больше опдходит для передачи ряда однотипных значений, но для этой цели в большинстве случаев  гораздо рациональнее использовать массив

Comment: +1 поставил еще сутра, но по поводу "запятая необязательна" - не стоит, это может привести к проблемам в будущих версиях компилятора, которым Вы пользуетесь. В стандарте, насколько я понимаю, запятая в параметрах обязательна.  
 --  
Я имел возможность на своем опыте почувствовать, к чему приводят такие хаки: в `vs8`, к примеру, можно было в параметрах к макросам передавать "пустые" параметры, а уже в `vs2010` эту возможность убрали. :)