# Переменное количество параметров c++

Tags: c++

Как передать неопределённое количество параметром, но если всего 1 параметр то передать только в первое место, если два то в два места

```
void func(...)
{
    std::string arr[5] = { "qwe",/*вот сюда №1*/ ,"rty", /*и сюда №2*/ };
    std::string u;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        u += arr[i];

    const char* d = u.c_str();
}
```

Comment: а если больше двух не рассматривается?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan рассматриваются, это просто для примера

Comment: `func(std::string a = "", std::string b = "") {return "qwe" + a + "rty" + b;}` подходит?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да подходит

Comment: На всякий случай - вы понимаете, что вместо `...` могут быть переданы не только строки, но и числа, какие-то объекты и так далее?... Что весьма небезопасно...

Comment: @Harry да понимаю

Comment: эта задачка (что в вопросе) не нуждается в решении через переменное количество агрументов функции, так как требует специализации под каждый вариант количества входных параметров. Если уж нужен вариант функции, которая принимает некое количество строк (2, 3, 10 и т.д.) и добавляет через одну другие строки, то лучшее (ИМХО) что можно сделать, это передавать в функцию список строк, а в функции (или это даже может быть параметр) определить другой список, со словами, котрорые нужно добавить. Это будет более универсальный и простой вариант.

Comment: Нашел как это можно сделать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/217941/333805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странный код конечно у вас для ваших намерений, но все же:

```
void func(std::initializer_list<std::string> arg)
{
    auto p = arg.begin(), q = arg.end();
    std::string arr[5] = 
    { "qwe", *p++,"rty", (p == q) ? "" : *p++, (p == q) ? "" : *p};
    std::string u;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        u += arr[i];
    const char* d = u.c_str();  
    //...
}

int main() { 
    func( { "123", "456", "789" });    
    func({ "abc", "def" });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ИМХО, статический массив все же не стоило брать из кода вопроса при том, что используете `initializer_list`

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, Тут  нет такого осмысленного кода, чтобы можно было демонстрировать правильное решение. Я просто скопировал и добавил ...

Comment: Согласен что странны, я воспользовался коментом HolyBlackCat под вопросом, так думаю будет лучше

Comment: так вы же сами сказали, что аргументов может быть больше, а теперь говорите, что с определенным количеством(а именно  с двумя аргументами)  лучше. Сначала определитесь что хотите  получать....

Comment: Лучше передать один string и парсить ее в функции